# Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowed

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to build a laravel app with an api for client apps, however I get this strange `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` and I don't understand why.

Here is the output for `php artisan route:list`:

[image: Output php artisan route:list]

And the request stuffs:

[image: Headers]
[image: Preview]

The errors happen while trying to POST to `api/v1/accounts` (as shown in the screenshots above).

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: On which route/url are you getting this error?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry: `api/v1/accounts`, I'll add it to the post

Comment: It would accept POST method, how are you accessing this url?

Comment: He's accessing it using POST request too, strange.

Comment: What's your form `action`?

Comment: Please [dont' use screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/616644).  They are kind of a pain...

Comment: @muuk you are getting not found error, are you able to access this url - `api/v1/accounts/login`

Comment: Hmm, strange I also can't access the accounts/login route. Weird, it only seems to apply to  the api routes

Comment: try this one:  `index.php/api/v1/accounts`

Comment: Just a guess, but can you try posting to `/api/v1/acounts` (notice the leading slash). I've run into instances where some piece of code doesn't add the leading slash and the router doesn't recognize the route and defaults to a GET request.

Comment: I am actually posting to a different url so my ajax is to http://url.com/etc

Answer (score 0):

Larval restful update api uses method PUT/PATCH.
Try add codes below into your `<form>` tag.
`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`